# Calling a controller/action through query parameters

Tags: laravel, symfony, model-view-controller, url-routing

Is it possible to call a controller and action directly by using query parameters in Laravel? I see some frameworks allow `/index.php?_controller=X&_action=Y`, or Yii allows `/index.php?r=X/Y`. I was wondering if something similar was possible in Laravel/Symfony.

Comment: It would not be hard (under Symfony at least) to add this sort of functionality.  Take a look at RouterListener::onKernelRequest for an example.  Maybe even just decorate the method.  But that fact that such functionality is not provided out of the box implies that it is not widely used.

Answer (score 0):

symfony

> The query string of a URL is not considered when matching routes. In this example, URLs like /blog?foo=bar and /blog?foo=bar&bar=foo will also match the blog_list route.

https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/routing.html

laravel afaik doesnt support that either

you are obviously free to just forward yourself

e.g. write one router that forwards to other controllers

symfony https://symfony.com/doc/6.1/controller/forwarding.html